# access unix variable via iab

Tags: shell, unix, vim

Suppose my unix/bash shell has a variable, "vimkeyword20170525", which can be accessed by

```
    printf "$vimkeyword20170525"
```

and this value might change from day to day.

Is there a way to get this into vim? I would like to put an "iab" line into .vimrc so that whenever I type "ssssss" inside vim (without the quotes), it is expanded / converted to the current $vimkeyword20170525 value, or at least the value that my shell had when I opened vim.

The following .vimrc line

```
    iab ssssss <Esc>db<Esc>!!printf "$vimkeyword20170525"<Esc>o
```

does this, but it will delete anything I typed between the previous "Escape" and "ssssss". Is there not a more elegant approach?

Comment: Is the shell variable 'just' a variable, or is it an exported environment variable?  It matters because environment variables are accessible in `vim` and any other program run from a shell where the environment variable is set.  By contrast, a 'plain' variable is only accessible in the shell — not in programs such as `vim` that have been executed frm the shell.  Does the name of the variable change, or just its value?

Comment: It is an exported environment variable. Its value may change but not its name. melpomene's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
iab ssssss <C-R>=$vimkeyword20170525<CR>
```

Ctrl-R inserts the contents of a register. `=` is a pseudo-register that prompts for an expression whose result is to be inserted. `$foo` is an expression that evaluates to the contents of the environment variable `foo`.